# Integral from Evans, PDE

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I'm reading the proof of solution to the heat equation (homogeneous problem, Theorem 1, pg. 48) and the last step is left to the reader, to verify that the integral $\frac{1}{t^{\frac{n}{2}}}\int_{\delta}^{+\infty} e^{-\frac{-r^2}{16t}}r^{n-1}dr \to 0$ as $t\to0^+$.

If I substitute $-\frac{-r^2}{16t}$ with $u$ I don't see where from there.

Comment: Do the change of variable $u= \frac{r}{\sqrt{t}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A change of variable $u= \frac{r}{\sqrt{t}}$ reduces the integral to $$\int_{\delta /\sqrt{t}}^{\infty} e^{-u^{2}/16}u^{n-1}\, du$$
Now if you know the dominated convergence theorem, then you are done. If not, then we simply borrow a factor from the exponential. That is for every $u\in [\frac{\delta}{t},\infty)$ we have that

$$e^{-u^{2}/16}=e^{-u^{2}/32}\, e^{-u^{2}/32} \leq e^{-\delta^{2}/32t} \, e^{-u^{2}/32}$$

This implies that your integral is bounded from above by a constant times $e^{-\delta^{2}/32t}$ which tends to zero, as $t\rightarrow 0 +$

Answer (score 1):

Let $r^2/16t=s$ or $r=4\sqrt{st}$. Then$$
   \frac{1}{t^{n/2}}\int_{\delta}^{\infty}e^{-r^2/16t}r^{n-1}dr
  = \frac{1}{t^{n/2}}\int_{\delta^2/16t}^{\infty}e^{-s}(4\sqrt{st})^{n-1}2\sqrt{t}\frac{ds}{\sqrt{s}} \\
  = \frac{(4\sqrt{t})^{n-1}2\sqrt{t}}{t^{n/2}}\int_{\delta^2/16t}^{\infty}e^{-s}s^{-1+n/2}ds \\
  = 4^{n+1}\int_{\delta^2/16t}^{\infty}e^{-s}s^{-1+n/2}ds.
$$